# Probability of normal distribution: average daily temperature - interpretation

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

> The City of Dallas has records indicating that the average daily temperature in the summer is 80 °F, which is normally distributed with a standard deviation of 3 °F.
>
> Based on these records, what is the probability of a daily temperature
>
> 1. between 75 °F and 87 °F
> 2. between 83 °F and 85 °F

$$P(X<75)=P(Z<-5/3)=0.0485$$
$$P(X<87)=P(Z<7/3)=0.9901$$
$$P(X<83)=P(Z<1)=0.8413$$
$$P(X<85)=P(Z<5/3)=0.9515$$
Am I following the right steps?

How do I interpret my data?

Comment: To finish the problem you still have some subtraction to do...

Comment: What do I need to subtract ?

Comment: @Sar Subtract the probability that the temperature is below the _lower_ value from that of the temperature below the _higher_ value. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. All that remains for you is to note that
$$P(a\le X\le b)=P(X\le b)-P(X\le a)$$
and that this holds for *any* continuous distribution $X$, including the standard normal distribution $Z$.

Comment: P(75<x<87) = P(x<0.9901) - (P(x<0.0485) ???

Comment: @Sar Just $0.9901-0.0485$.

Comment: Thanks:
Does it mean that 94.16 % of the time temp. is between 75 and 87 F ?

Comment: You can say that, mhm...

Comment: Thanks!  Parcly Taxel. Green tick (yes). Your answer was very useful!